# Handling of redundant product data in SAP material integration

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub, sap-cpi

The SAP standard material integration* wants to create for each salesOrg a different Catalog. Therefore, the products are redundantly saved in each catalog which leads to a huge amount of redundant data in SAP Commerce, because the products are often in all catalogs.

So for example, if you have 100,000 products and 10 sales Orgs and 3 distribution channels each, you have (100,000 * 10 * 3) + 100,000 products in Commerce. Ok, this example is a bit unrealistic, but the problem of redundant data exists...

How do you handle it?

*: CPI: https://help.sap.com/viewer/9b7fba7fb23645fcb03d294ddee98752/2005/en-US/a05c7205588549768f66d323a04cabf7.html?q=sapcpiproductexchange
Old DataHub is quite the same.

Comment: what is `SAP standard material integration`? it is not a common name, describe the product/process you use

Comment: Ok, added a reference, but I would say that there is only one "Standard" except that there a different platforms like SCPI and Datahub.